# How to add log tracking system to existing asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, logging, elmah

Recently I have to maintain multiple existing application that don't have a nice desire Log system.

Most of the time it will be depend on EventLog and it does not perform well if it's front-end issue.

My question is how should I add either Elmah or Log4net to existing project to 
with minor effort of changing existing application.

I tried using Log4net before, but seems like to log backend issue, you will need to add in exception from backend code, which will cost alot of effort for my case

Any other tool that provide great looging and minor effort will be appreciated, too

Answer (score 1):

Since both ELMAH and log4net are free tools, you also have the option of using these and logging to a local database, file, or similar. I wrote an eBook about how to do that: [.NET Web Application Logging Essentials](https://leanpub.com/net-web-application-logging-essentials). If you would like a copy, I can provide you with one by writing me at thomas at elmah.io.

I would also like to mention, that I'm the founder of [elmah.io](https://elmah.io/), a cloud-based service for handling exceptions from your web apps. We support both ELMAH and log4net and the installation is extremely easy. It's a paid service, so it's up to you if you can live with the limitations of the free versions.

Comment: thank you Thomas, but i forgot to mention, i'm looking for a free version, actually, thanks for your advise

Comment: Totally fine. The ebook actually shows you how to set up ELMAH (free) and log4net (free) on ASP.NET/MVC/WebAPI/Core if you're interested.

Comment: I actually use elmah.io on a couple of projects. It's pretty easy to use and provide great value. I actually spotted some errors pretty early compared to my previous error/logging solutions